# SQL Server : first time connect fails

Tags: sql-server

I installed SQL Server Management Studio and at server name put a dot and at first time I try to connect I get an error:

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to ..
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)
>
> The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: can you check windows services sqlserver service started or not.

Comment: Which **edition** of SQL Server (the **database engine/core** did you install? Mgmt Studio is **only** the GUI management tool - it does **NOT** contain the actual database engine. And the default instance for SQL Server **Express** (if you installed that) would be `.\SQLEXPRESS` - not just `.`

Comment: I didn't know I had to install database engine. How do I do that?